# Iteration and moving files in Bash

Tags: bash, for-loop

I am trying to write a script that will accomplish:

1. Read all files in directory
2. If a file is equal to one of the specified files, rename it and move it to directory XXX

I got the loop to iterate over the files but it keeps giving me an error.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `ls`
do
  if [  '$i'  -eq 's1' -o  '$i'  -eq 's2' -o  '$i'  -eq 's3'  ]; then

     #rename file and move it to XXX

  fi
done
```

this gives me an error of loops: line 6: [: $i: integer expression expected

Also how would I change the name of the iterator *i* to names like t1, t2, t3

ie. if the iterator is holding the value of s1 I want to rename it to t1.

Comment: `||` is not part of `[` syntax.

Comment: 1. `for i in *`. 2. `"$i"`; `'$i'` doesn't expand the variable. 3. `-eq` compares integers, use `=` for strings.

Comment: I want to check if the name the iterator holds has the same name value as s1 or s2 etc...

Comment: the code works now, I appreciate all the feedback

Comment: To compare strings you have to use == and not -eq which is used for integer comparision]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in ./*; do
    [[ -f $i && $i == s[123] ]] && mv -f -- "$i" "t${i#s}"
done
```

The only notable thing to say is don't use `ls` in a script like this. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: To rename "s1" to "t1": `mv -f -- "$i" "${i/s/t}"`

Answer (score 2):

Just test for a range

```
shopt -s nullglob
for i in s[1-3]; do mv -i "$i" "${i/s/t}"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error because your shell is reading `if CMD1 || CMD2 || CMD3` where

```
CMD1 is [ '$1$ -eq 's1'
CMD2 is '$i'  -eq 's2'
CMD3 is '$i'  -eq 's3' ]
```

The boolean *OR* operation is represented by `-o` when using the `test` command. There is four other things to fix in your script:

1. Single quotes are not expanded, so that `'$i' -eq 's1'` should actually be `"$i" -eq 's1'`.
2. The use of backquote expansion is deprecated in favour of `$(…)`.
3. You should not parse the output of `ls` as it is very brittle, use instead shell globbing here.
4. The `-eq` operator tests for *numeric* equality, you want to use `=` instead.

With this in mind:

```
for i in *
do
  if [  "$i"  = 's1' -o  "$i"  = 's2' -o  "$i" = 's3' ]; then
     #rename file and move it to XXX
  fi
done
```

Comment: `-eq` is numeric equality. You want `=`

Comment: `-eq` should probably be `=`. Also usual advice about avoiding `-o` since this exceeds the max number of args for tests defined by POSIX.

Comment: @ormaaj Thank you for pointing that. The OP explicitly uses `bash` where `test` is a builtin so argument limitations are not a real issue here.